# What's the proper way to bind an Angular2 observable asynchronously to a template?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to bind an Angular2 Http Observable to a template using a service.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SourceService} from "./source.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-source',
  templateUrl: './source.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./source.component.css']
})
export class SourceComponent implements OnInit {

  private dtoSources: Observable<SourceFile[]>;

  constructor(public service:SourceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('call ngOninit');
    this.dtoSources = this.service.get()
  }
}

export interface SourceFile {
  id: number;
  locationURL: string;
}
```

Using the following service:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {SourceFile} from "./source.component";

@Injectable()
export class SourceService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  get(): Observable<SourceFile[]> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/source', {headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json() );
  }

  private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
}
```

With this template:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let value of dtoSources | async">
{{value.id}} : {{ value.locationURL }}</li>
</ul>
```

This gets the following error. Why doesn't the `async` pipe allow for the call to complete prior to rendering?

```
error_handler.js:47EXCEPTION: Error in ./SourceComponent class SourceComponent - inline template:4:8 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:49ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:49next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:52ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:53Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgFor.ngOnChanges (ng_for.js:128)
    at Wrapper_NgFor.detectChangesInInputProps (wrapper.ngfactory.js:45)
    at _View_SourceComponent0.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:67)
    at _View_SourceComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:219)
    at _View_SourceComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:324)
    at _View_SourceComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:245)
    at _View_SourceComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (host.ngfactory.js:33)
    at _View_SourceComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:219)
    at _View_SourceComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:324)
    at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:237)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
error_handler.js:56ERROR CONTEXT:
```

Comment: Did you tried to declare the `array` like this? `private dtoSources: SourceFile[];` and in method do like this: `this.service.get().subscribe((data) => this.dtoSources = data);`?

Comment: i though you could use async pipe to not have to call subscribe

Comment: The problem is that `response.json()` doesn't return an array but an object.

Comment: wrapping it in [ response.json() ] fixes it. However, I thought the return object inside the map callback sets the value for each new array element? (i'll answer the question in a full comment once i understand the core issue )